# References does not show in the occurrence order - thesis

Tags: citing

I want my references to show up in the order of appearance in the text so that the [1] would be the first citation and [2] would be the last one. In the beginning, it was doing it but after a while, I changed some pages so that let's say citation 100 is replaced with citation 90. However, my latex does not update the number of citations. Could you guide me through a quick solution such as deleting a file and re-compile to sort this ordering issue?

This is for my thesis and I have a main script where I input different chapters. My code is in the main.tex is:

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{myBibs}
```

then in the chapters, I have:

```
\cite{einstein1905}
```

The main code that I call my chapters (in the preamble there is nothing regarding the referencing):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{multirow}

\include{thesis.preamble}

%% Sets up the area of text on your page

\textwidth 14cm

\textheight 25cm

\oddsidemargin=1.8cm

\evensidemargin=1.8cm

\begin{document}

% [-] Title Page

\title{ }

\author{ }

\normallinespacing

\maketitle

% -------------------------------------------

% [-] Preface Pages

% -------------------------------------------

% including and ordered by:

% 1. a front page

% 2. Abstract

% 3. Acknowledgements

% 4. List of Publications

% 5. Contents

% 6. List of Tables

% 7. List of Figures

\preface

\input{prefaces/abstract}

\input{prefaces/acknowledgements}

\input{prefaces/list_of_symbols}

% -------------------------------------------

% [-] Main Body 

% -------------------------------------------

% body of thesis goes here.

\body

% [-] Introduction

\input{body/chapter1}

% [-] Literature Review

% -------------------------------------------

% [-] Bibliography and Appendix

% -------------------------------------------

\clearpage

\newpage

\begin{spacing}{1.0}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\bibliography{myBibs_v2}

% appendices come here

\input{appendices/appendix}

\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

Assuming we have a single chapter (Introduction):

```
\chapter{Introduction}


\section{Motivation}


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit \cite{iata2021}. Nam gravida ligula at erat aliquam, eu sollicitudin ligula varius\cite{ourdata2020}.
```

Comment: you just need to re-run bibtex to regenerate the bibliography in the new order after an edit

Comment: more exactly after an edit run latex to re-generate the raw data, run bibtex to re generate the reference list, run latex again to see the typeset list

Comment: Hi David. Thanks. How do I need to re-run BibTeX? I do F8 on my keyboard and re-compiled several times but still does not work.

Comment: I run bibtex by typing `bibtex` on the commandline (I run pdflatex by typing `pdflatex`)  If you have a menu or keyboard shortcut in your editor that is a feature of the editor. You haven't said what you are using.

Comment: Hi David, thanks. I am using a latex editor (on TexStudio). I run BibTeX and latex thesis several times but the number of citations did not change in my thesis. (i.e. first reference appearing is still looking as [11]).

Comment: you need to show an example if you want someone to debug your code. But check the `.blg` bibtex log whoch will show any bibtex errors that may have prevented it regenerating, also check for citations in table captions which can appear in the table of contents so grab earlier numbers than you expect

Comment: Thank David, I am trying to add my Latex code. I really appreciate if you can have quick look.

Comment: there is nothing in the code that you show related to the problem. It is just a list of `\input` referencing unshown files.  Note howveer yor settings `\textwidth 14cm` etc completely undo teh settings made by the geometry package.

Comment: Hi David, thanks. At the bottom there are 2 lines regarding the bibliography. What would you need else? By the way, I tried " %\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex} " but this code in the preamble did not work for me.

Comment: you are asking about a `\cite` that gives the wrong number, but there are no `\cite` in this example and no code that anyone can run to debug the issue. make a small complete example that produces the wrong output.

Comment: I have slightly changed the code. Under the main script, I created an example of my first two references which are in my first chapter. When I compile, my references start with [11] and [12] rather than being numbered as [1] and [2].

Comment: well.. I still can not run that example and see any bad (or good) output.  Even if I made a bibliography with those two entries and removed the `\input` of the appendix I am sure I would get `[1]`and `[2]`  in _this_ example. You presumably have a citation `[1]`_somewhere_? where is it? are you sure it is not earler, eg in in a table of contents?

Comment: if you are using biblatex then my comments about bibtex are wrong as you need to use biber, Sorry I give up it is impossible to give any more help without seeing an example.

Comment: Hi David, thanks. I am sure the the first citation is \cite{iata2021} and second one is \cite{ourdata2020}. What would you need to be able to compile it yourself? Do you need the preamble as well?

Comment: you can easily tell what anyone would need: do as you are asking others to do, copy the code you post to a new directory run it and check it produces unexpected reference numbers. Delete everything that you can delete while still checking that the example shows the problem.

Comment: Hi David, alright I am working on that. However, I realized that when I comment out one of my entire chapters or even all the references are still displayed in full in the same order as before. I think the problem is to trigger an update regarding the reference list.

Comment: well as I said in the very first comment, you need to re-run bibtex if you edit the document.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks. The problem is solved. As you warned me, my Latex was taking references in the captions (from let's say page 100) as [1] and not the first citation in my page 1 which should be [1]. I deleted the citations at the table captions and deleted all my auxiliary files. Then the problem was solved. Many thanks.